# Ruby collection of strings as a parameter

Tags: ruby, parameters

I have a `players()` method that returns all players names.

I want to use this, as a parameter to twitter streaming, like this:

```
@client.track(players) do |tweet|
```

The gem does not allow it, so I have to do this:

```
@client.track('player1', 'player2', 'player3') do |tweet|
```

But that's terrible, since I have so many players.

Is that a way to parse my array into that list of strings?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is `*`, the "splat" operator:

```
players = [ "player1", "player2", "player3" ]
@client.track( *players )

# ...is equivalent to...

@client.track( "player1", "player2", "player3" )
```

Putting a splat before any object that responds to `to_ary` (like an Array, Hash, and most other Enumerables) will transform its items into an argument list. It's very handy and you'll see it a lot as you explore more Ruby code. Here's another example:

```
a = [ 3, 4 ]

[ 1, 2 ].push( a )  # no splat
# => [ 1, 2, [ 3, 4 ] ]

[ 1, 2 ].push( *a ) # splat!
# => [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

You can use it directly on objects, too—not just variables:

```
[ 1, 2, *[ 3, 4 ] ]
# => [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```